# Load data in background and reload tableView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm

I use realm database and make load data from db in background queue. Data from database must to load in background and after must be reload view(TableView). How i can make reload data on tableView in main thread?

this method for load data:

```
func loadMenu(category: String) -> [Recipe] {

        var ingredient = [Ingredient]()
        var stage = [CookStage]()
        var photo = [PhotoDish]()
        var recipe = [Recipe]()
        DispatchQueue(label: "background").async {
            autoreleasepool {
                let realm = try! Realm()

                let data = realm.objects(Dish.self).filter("type = '\(category)'")
                print(data)
                for (index, value) in data.enumerated() {

                    for valIngredient in value.ingredient {
                        let ing = ["recipeID": valIngredient.recipeID,
                                   "name": valIngredient.name,
                                   "count": valIngredient.count,
                                   "weight": valIngredient.weight,
                                   "photo": valIngredient.photoURL,
                                   "image": self.loadImage(url: valIngredient.photoURL, dir: "ingredients") ] as [String: AnyObject]
                        let newIngredient = Ingredient(dict: ing as Dictionary<String,AnyObject>)
                        ingredient.append(newIngredient)
                    }
                    for valCook in value.cook {
                        let cook = ["stage": valCook.stage,
                                    "recipeID": valCook.recipeID,
                                    "photoUrl": valCook.photoUrl,
                                    "photo": self.loadImage(url: valCook.photoUrl, dir: "stage")] as [String:AnyObject]
                        let newStage = CookStage(dict: cook as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)
                        stage.append(newStage)
                    }
                    for valFoto in value.foto {
                        let foto = ["url": valFoto.url,
                                    "recipeID": valFoto.recipeID,
                                    "image": self.loadImage(url: valFoto.url, dir: "compleate")] as [String:AnyObject]
                        let newPhoto = PhotoDish(dict: foto as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)
                        photo.append(newPhoto)
                    }
                    let newElement = Recipe(name: value.name, count: value.eat, complexity: value.complexity, time: value.time, category: value.category, type: value.type, about: value.about, ingredient: ingredient, cook: stage, photo: photo, idOwner: value.idOwner, shared: value.shared, planing: value.planing, recipeID: value.recipeID)
                    recipe.append(newElement)
                }
            }
        }
        return recipe
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use Collection Notifications instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// Please use completion Handlers.

```
func loadMenu(category: String, completion:@escaping([Recipe]?)->Swift.Void) 
{
    completion(recipe)  
}


    loadMenu("your category",completion:{(recipe:[Recipe]?) in 
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        recipeofyourtableview  =  recipe
        self.yourTableView.reloadData()
    }
})
```

Comment: perfect! Thank you very much. It was so simple.

Answer (score 1):

Once your data is loaded on the background thread, use:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    myTable.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the controller loads faster than the data is loaded.

Comment: then set yourself a control variable like “dataIsReady” boolean that you initially set to false, and set to true before your dispatch.  In your tableview data source, if dataIsReady is false, return numberOfRows as 0